# C Program to convert word columns into integer

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program in c to calculate the integer value of a word column.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int GetValue(char ch){
        int c=ch;
        if(ch>='a'&&ch<='z'){
                return abs(96-c);
        } 
        if(ch>='A'&&ch<='Z'){
                return abs(64-c);
        }
        return -1;
}

void main()
{
        char col[10];
        char *str;
        int len,sum=0,temp=0,i;
        printf("Enter the column string : ");
        scanf("%s",&col);
        len = strlen(col);
        memcpy(str,col,len);
        str[len]='\0';
        printf("Entered characters are %s and its length is %i",col,len);

        for(i=0;i<len;i++){
                sum+=GetValue(str[i])*(pow(26,len-1-(temp++)));
        }

        printf("Value of column is %d",sum);
}
```

**When I compile it it gives 3 warnings**

columnno.c:20:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’ [-Wformat=]
  scanf("%s",&col);
  ^

columnno.c:21:8: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’ [enabled by default]
  len = strlen(col);
        ^

columnno.c:22:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memcpy’ [enabled by default]
  memcpy(str,col,len);
  ^

**Output**

Enter the column string : abc

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Please Help!!!

Comment: In Addition to Rohan's Answer, you can use `malloc` also to provide memory to pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.
No need to pass address of array to `scanf()` with `%s`.

```
scanf("%s",&col);
```

Change to

```
scanf("%s",col);
```

2.
Before doing `memcpy(str,col,len);` you should allocate memory to `str` as its `char *`. Otherwise you are accessing random value in `str` as memory location, causing undefined behavior - most likely segmentation fault.

So better would be using `strdup()`.

Change

```
memcpy(str,col,len);
str[len]='\0';
```

To

```
str = strdup(col);
```

However, make sure your input string is not more than 9 characters, so that its stored appropriately in `cols`.

Comment: Add string.h header file

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answer. Include the library header file for `strlen()`

```
#include<string.h>
```

It includes the definition of function `strlen()`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting these warnings because you are trying to use a previously undeclared function.

To fix the problem, you have to declare the functions before using them; normally you do this by including the appropriate header. 
try `#include <string.h>`
That's where `strcpy` and `strncpy` are defined.

And you will get runtime error in your code, because you are storing something in `str`, without allocating any memory to it.